# Realistic performance testing of C functions

Tags: c, caching, profiling

I am currently benchmarking some functions by calling a function 1 million
times and measuring how long (wall clock) time this takes. Example code:

```
/* start timer */

for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {

    /* call my function here */
}

/* stop timer, result = diff/i */
```

However the function is executed extremely fast because
the code/data is loaded into L1 cache on executed from there.
This is not a realistic scenario, as other code will be executed
in between.

Is there a way to flush or delete the L1 cache in each loop iteration,
so there my function is executed from external RAM ?

Thanks

Comment: Won't the time to load the code/data from RAM be exactly the same for every possible implementation? Why do you want to measure your RAM performance? What's your goal?

Comment: Have a look **http://www.agner.org/optimize/**

Answer (score 0):

I think not. I was looking for ways to force use of the cache for a project I was working on and the research was saying that the OS pretty much handles all that for you. You probably need a much bigger data set to force the use of RAM, because the caches are pretty large on modern machines.

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate what the functions are doing. If you are simply executing the same function, with the same data, that produces the same result each time, optimisation will execute it only once, or not at all, if you do not use the result.

What timer are you using. You need one similar to the following, if you want accuracy.

```
  void getSecs()
  {
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp1);

     theseSecs =  tp1.tv_sec + tp1.tv_nsec / 1e9;               
     return;
  }

Ow Windows using

QueryPerformanceCounter(&astarttime);
```

If you the function instructions to be loaded from RAM each time, the only way would be to have numerous copies of the same code, that is a sufficient number to increase the total running time to be within resolution of the timer. Even then, there could be wide variations is calculated speeds.